# Django find which form was submitted

Tags: django, formset

I have 3 formsets in a single template.  Only one would be visible at a given time (the other two are hidden entirely):

```
<form style="display: none;">
```

All 3 forms are rendered with default values and should be valid even if no data was entered.

However, I would like to know which one was submitted when I validate the views.py.

In views.py I have the following:

```
def submitted(request):

    f1 = formset1(request.POST)
    f2 = formset2(request.POST)
    f3 = formset3(request.POST)

    if f1.is_valid() or f2.is_valid() or f3.is_valid():
        f1.save()
        f2.save()
        f3.save()
        # Do a lot of calculations...

        return render(request, 'submitted.html')
```

The problem is that I don't want f2 or f3 saved if only f1 was submitted (each formset has their own submit button).  The '# Do a lot of calculations...' part is quite extensive and I don't want to replicate the code unnecessarily.

How can I use the same view, but only save and do the calculations for only the submitted formset?

Comment: The ID of whichever submit button was clicked will be in `request.POST`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I am not sure what you mean though - sorry!  I tried viewing f1.id in the submitted.html and did not see anything?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If each form has it's own submit button:

```
<form id='form1'>
    ...
    <input type='submit' name='submit-form1' value='Form 1' />
</form>
<form id='form2'>
    ...
    <input type='submit' name='submit-form2' value='Form 2' />
</form>
<form id='form3'>
    ...
    <input type='submit' name='submit-form3' value='Form 3' />
</form>
```

Then the name of the submit button will be in `request.POST` for whichever form was submitted:

```
'submit-form1' in request.POST # True if Form 1 was submitted
'submit-form2' in request.POST # True if Form 2 was submitted
'submit-form3' in request.POST # True if Form 3 was submitted
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced a similar issue where I had several forms in a template and I need to know which one was submitted. To do this I used the submit button.

Let's say you have the forms like this:

```
<form yourcode>
    # ... ...
    # your input fields
    # ... ... 
    <input method="post" type="submit" name="action" class="yourclass" value="Button1" />
</form>

<form yourcode>
    # ... ...
    # your input fields
    # ... ... 
    <input method="post" type="submit" name="action" class="yourclass" value="Button2" />
</form>
```

You can read the difference between those submit buttons, the value of the first is **Button1** and the second is **Button2**

In your view you can have a control like this:

```
def yourview():
    # ... ... 
    # Your code
    # ... ... 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['action'] == "Button1":
            # This is the first form being submited
            # Do whatever you need with first form

        if request.POST['action'] == "Button2":
            # This is the second form being submited
            # Do whatever you need with second form
```

So, you can control which form is submitted using the value of the button. There is other ways to do that, but this way was the easier for my issue.

*You can also use the **name** property to filter the forms*